# Access to registry denied importing entries

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, import

I am trying to create a logon script for local users (there is no domain). So I have taken backups of the registries from baseline machines and I am trying to use them as the entries I want to apply.

I have a simple batch file that follows...

```
@echo off
reg import C:\%directory%
```

But whether I run as admin or not, I get

> Error accessing registry

Cannot figure out why

Comment: This on an active domain by chance?

Comment: No sir, I stated no domain

Comment: While you said "local" user you still have local users in a domain environment.  This sounds like a pure permission problem.  I would add this permission to your User group and test it then.

Comment: There is no AD/DC. It is just a single workstation.